# Got error on snap installing package, but package was installed

Tags: ansible

I use my own Ansible image ([repository here](https://github.com/sineverba/docker-ansible)) and I use [this playbook](https://github.com/sineverba/docker-ansible/blob/master/playbook/desktop.yml).

When playbook comes to SNAP package (e.g. on Visual studio code setup)

```yaml
- name: Setup Visual Studio Code via Snap
  become: yes
  community.general.snap:
    name: code
    classic: yes
```

I get in console following error:

```bash
TASK [Setup Visual Studio Code via Snap] ****************************************************
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: ansible_collections.community.general.plugins.module_utils.mh.exceptions.ModuleHelperException
fatal: [192.168.1.39]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "channel": null, "classic": true, "cmd": "['state', 'classic', 'channel', 'dangerous', 'code']", "msg": "Ooops! Snap installation failed while executing '['state', 'classic', 'channel', 'dangerous', 'code']', please examine logs and error output for more details.", "output": {"channel": null, "classic": true, "cmd": "['state', 'classic', 'channel', 'dangerous', 'code']", "snap_names": ["code"], "snaps_installed": ["code"]}, "snap_names": ["code"], "snaps_installed": ["code"], "vars": {"channel": null, "classic": true, "cmd": "['state', 'classic', 'channel', 'dangerous', 'code']", "snap_names": ["code"], "snaps_installed": ["code"]}}
```

And Ansible execution stops. But, in reality, in target system, Code is installed! Same for others following packages.

I don't want really add some skip errors.

#### Update 1

I launched ansible with verbose mode and got, for next package

```bash
The full traceback is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ansible_community.general.snap_payload_dfli23fx/ansible_community.general.snap_payload.zip/ansible_collections/community/general/plugins/module_utils/mh/deco.py", line 52, in wrapper
    func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/tmp/ansible_community.general.snap_payload_dfli23fx/ansible_community.general.snap_payload.zip/ansible_collections/community/general/plugins/module_utils/mh/base.py", line 80, in run
    self.__run__()
  File "/tmp/ansible_community.general.snap_payload_dfli23fx/ansible_community.general.snap_payload.zip/ansible_collections/community/general/plugins/module_utils/mh/mixins/state.py", line 37, in __run__
    return func()
  File "/tmp/ansible_community.general.snap_payload_dfli23fx/ansible_community.general.snap_payload.zip/ansible_collections/community/general/plugins/modules/snap.py", line 411, in state_present
  File "/tmp/ansible_community.general.snap_payload_dfli23fx/ansible_community.general.snap_payload.zip/ansible_collections/community/general/plugins/modules/snap.py", line 399, in _present
  File "/tmp/ansible_community.general.snap_payload_dfli23fx/ansible_community.general.snap_payload.zip/ansible_collections/community/general/plugins/module_utils/mh/base.py", line 40, in do_raise
    raise _MHE(*args, **kwargs)
ansible_collections.community.general.plugins.module_utils.mh.exceptions.ModuleHelperException
fatal: [192.168.1.39]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "channel": null,
    "classic": true,
    "cmd": "['state', 'classic', 'channel', 'dangerous', 'phpstorm']",
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "channel": null,
            "classic": true,
            "dangerous": false,
            "name": [
                "phpstorm"
            ],
            "options": null,
            "state": "present"
        }
    },
    "msg": "Ooops! Snap installation failed while executing '['state', 'classic', 'channel', 'dangerous', 'phpstorm']', please examine logs and error output for more details.",
    "output": {
        "channel": null,
        "classic": true,
        "cmd": "['state', 'classic', 'channel', 'dangerous', 'phpstorm']",
        "snap_names": [
            "phpstorm"
        ],
        "snaps_installed": [
            "phpstorm"
        ]
    },
    "snap_names": [
        "phpstorm"
    ],
    "snaps_installed": [
        "phpstorm"
    ],
    "vars": {
        "channel": null,
        "classic": true,
        "cmd": "['state', 'classic', 'channel', 'dangerous', 'phpstorm']",
        "snap_names": [
            "phpstorm"
        ],
        "snaps_installed": [
            "phpstorm"
        ]
    }
}
```

#### Update 2

Seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76598863/how-to-fix-ansible-snap-package-installation-error), tried adding channel but no luck:

```bash
The full traceback is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ansible_community.general.snap_payload_9_hra6k8/ansible_community.general.snap_payload.zip/ansible_collections/community/general/plugins/module_utils/mh/deco.py", line 52, in wrapper
    func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/tmp/ansible_community.general.snap_payload_9_hra6k8/ansible_community.general.snap_payload.zip/ansible_collections/community/general/plugins/module_utils/mh/base.py", line 80, in run
    self.__run__()
  File "/tmp/ansible_community.general.snap_payload_9_hra6k8/ansible_community.general.snap_payload.zip/ansible_collections/community/general/plugins/module_utils/mh/mixins/state.py", line 37, in __run__
    return func()
  File "/tmp/ansible_community.general.snap_payload_9_hra6k8/ansible_community.general.snap_payload.zip/ansible_collections/community/general/plugins/modules/snap.py", line 411, in state_present
  File "/tmp/ansible_community.general.snap_payload_9_hra6k8/ansible_community.general.snap_payload.zip/ansible_collections/community/general/plugins/modules/snap.py", line 399, in _present
  File "/tmp/ansible_community.general.snap_payload_9_hra6k8/ansible_community.general.snap_payload.zip/ansible_collections/community/general/plugins/module_utils/mh/base.py", line 40, in do_raise
    raise _MHE(*args, **kwargs)
ansible_collections.community.general.plugins.module_utils.mh.exceptions.ModuleHelperException
fatal: [192.168.1.39]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "channel": "latest/stable",
    "classic": false,
    "cmd": "['state', 'classic', 'channel', 'dangerous', 'postman']",
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "channel": "latest/stable",
            "classic": false,
            "dangerous": false,
            "name": [
                "postman"
            ],
            "options": null,
            "state": "present"
        }
    },
    "msg": "Ooops! Snap installation failed while executing '['state', 'classic', 'channel', 'dangerous', 'postman']', please examine logs and error output for more details.",
    "output": {
        "channel": "latest/stable",
        "classic": false,
        "cmd": "['state', 'classic', 'channel', 'dangerous', 'postman']",
        "snap_names": [
            "postman"
        ],
        "snaps_installed": [
            "postman"
        ]
    },
    "snap_names": [
        "postman"
    ],
    "snaps_installed": [
        "postman"
    ],
    "vars": {
        "channel": "latest/stable",
        "classic": false,
        "cmd": "['state', 'classic', 'channel', 'dangerous', 'postman']",
        "snap_names": [
            "postman"
        ],
        "snaps_installed": [
            "postman"
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved after some research.
Issue is Ansible Galaxy version.
Downgraded to 6.6.0 works.

Command: `ansible-galaxy collection install community.general:==6.6.0`

[See bug here.](https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.general/issues/7265)